# Javascript callback on a file uploader

Tags: javascript, callback

Here is an example of how to create a FileUpload button in javascript (from w3schools, but it's pretty generic).

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "file");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

To get at the file(s) itself we must use the files[] property of the button, but I believe a callback must be used.  While I understand the concept of callbacks in principle, I'm not sure how to apply it to this situation.  Only one file will be uploaded in my case, but feel free to give the general answer.

Basically, when I try to grab the files[0] it generates an error when the file picker launches without waiting to complete.  That's why I think a callback is needed.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Here is some code that doesn't work.  It's just two files added to the above.  There are no error messages, the file picker comes up, and "File contents: undefined" is logged when the picker comes up.

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "file");
document.body.appendChild(x);
x.click();
console.log("File contents: " + x.files[0]);
```

My only real goal here is to get it so the last line works instead of showing undefined.  I.e. I have the actual file.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the error you receive.

Comment: At which moment you try to get files[0]?  Do you have an eventListener on "change" for your input?

Comment: Thanks for the comments folks.  See the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using creates an **input** tag which does not have multiple attribute set. In your case you would not get an array but just a single file object.
To enable multiple selections you need to set *multiple* attribute.

You could try this

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "file");
  x.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

**To read the selected file**
There are basic ways to read the user selected file
1. Post the form inwhich case you will get the file in POST params
2. Get a reference to **INPUT** tag and then access the selected file

To upload a file you should generally go with the second option and you can do that as follows.

```
var inputTag = document.querySelectorAll('input'); // querySelectorAll returns an array so you will need to access the tag with proper index
var selectedFile = inputTag[0].files;// you will find the selected file in **files** property of the inputTag.
```

To read the selected file contents you need to use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). For a complete example on how to use it [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is a great tutorial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case as I said I only need one file.  I'm just looking for how to actually have the file at the end.

Comment: I just tried this with console.log(selectedFile).  It logged a "filelist:
 {length: 0}" to the console at the time the dialog box launches, not after getting the file.  In other words this method also does not wait for the results.  It needs a callback or something... ?  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Please check the updated code. Also you should try using events to start uploading a file when the user selects any file.

Comment: I was using the updated code.  However, the tutorial you mentioned at the end of your post is really helpful.   I'm thinking the .files object contains metadata about the file, but not the contents.  I need to use the FileReader object to actually get at the contents.  I accepted your answer because the tutorial you refer to is where I need to be.  Thanks.